# git ignore all files in subfolders of subfolders

Tags: typescript, git, github, strapi

I am using strapi with the documentation-/swagger-plugin. Every time I change something or add a new controller, the documentation rebuilds.

How can I make git ignore all files in /documentation/*.json ?

[github-desktop example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrI4o.png)

I tried * / documentation / *.json in my .gitignore but that didnt work.
Just adding *.json is not a option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `**` like `**/documentation/*.json`

Comment: amazing, it works. now, i dont need to worry every time, which files are selected to push!